# hash value not coming correct while using @ in the string

Tags: perl, hash, hashcode

I am trying to generate a hash value using this code

```
use Digest::SHA qw(sha1_hex); print sha1_hex("prady@prady.com")
```

The generated value is

> 642732893b7d25cf6a47773fa1c4988fac2ff3ad

When i check the hash code using the free generator

http://sha1-hash-online.waraxe.us/

i get the hash code as

> e49ece87a60590483bb74c24e82f9d64d13d98c1

I performed the same test by removing the @ symbol from the string
i get matching values from the website as well as the code.
Both return me the same hash code

> 08e1698b5818d8fdf0f7b31132c3b44c49671644

Of the ones generated by the code and website which is the correct one ? Is this a known behavior while using @ symbol on string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `@something` inside a double-quoted string is interpreted as an array name by Perl. You would have caught that mistake if you'd used `use warnings;` and `use strict;`. The solution is simple: escape the `@`, like this: `print sha1_hex("some\@where.org")`. Or use single-quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks.. this makes sense. thanks for the explanation.. Saved me a lot of headache :)

Answer (score 4):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Contrary to your claim, there's no `@` in your string.

Comment: the string used is prady@prady.com. I am completely new to perl forgive my ignorance on usage of strict and warning.. Will incorporate them

Comment: No, the string literal `"prady@prady.com"` creates the string `prady.com`. Use `use strict; use warnings;`! Always!

Comment: This was something which i was not aware of. Only after reading mortiz answer did i realize it. As i told i am a complete novice in Perl

Comment: Yup, that's why I was letting you discover. Adding `use strict;` would have pointed out the error.